# XAMPP: can't get PHP to work

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I saved a .php file to file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/tester/tester.php, and though my XHTML and CSS are working, my PHP is not. I put

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

as the first line of the body, and

<?php
echo "<p>Hello World</p>";
?>

a couple of paragraphs in. But when I view the page, nothing for phpinfo() shows up at all, and the Hello World bit shows up as:

Hello World"; ?>

Apache and MySQL are running. I've scoured the internet and can't find a solution, but I feel like it's probably something very basic that I'm missing.

Comment: pretty sure that your apache is not configured correctly, no php processing is being done.

Comment: OK... how do I configure it correctly?

Comment: XAMPP should pretty much work out of the box, so a reinstall could probably fix it, but most likely you are missing a `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` somewhere in your Apache configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call your file with

> **localhost**/tester/tester.php

instead of `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/tester/tester.php`.